# How do I crate a value of type a{sv} for a call to org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify via DBus?

Tags: haskell, notifications, dbus, freedesktop.org

I'm experimenting with [DBus](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus-1.3.2/docs/DBus.html) in an attempt to understand the [Desktop Notifications Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/notification-spec/notification-spec-latest.html).

At the latter link I read that the method `Notify` has this signature

> ```
> UINT32 org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify ( app_name,    
>                                               replaces_id,     
>                                               app_icon,    
>                                               summary,     
>                                               body,    
>                                               actions,     
>                                               hints,   
>                                               expire_timeout); 
> STRING app_name;
> UINT32 replaces_id;
> STRING app_icon;
> STRING summary;
> STRING body;
> as actions;
> a{sv} hints;
> INT32 expire_timeout;
> ```

where the argument `hints` has type `a{sv}`, and is commented as follows:

> Optional hints that can be passed to the server from the client program. Although clients and servers should never assume each other supports any specific hints, they can be used to pass along information, such as the process PID or window ID, that the server may be able to make use of. See Hints. Can be empty.

So I tried to write a little haskell program that makes a call providing some dummy arguments, thinking that "Optional hints" would mean `Maybe`,

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Int
import Data.Word
import Data.List (sort)
import DBus
import DBus.Client
import DBus.Internal.Types
import GHC.Generics

main = do
    client <- connectSession

    call_ client (methodCall "/org/freedesktop/Notifications" "org.freedesktop.Notifications" "Notify")
        { methodCallDestination = Just "org.freedesktop.Notifications"
        , methodCallBody = [ toVariant ("" :: String)
                           , toVariant (1 :: Word32)
                           , toVariant ("" :: String)
                           , toVariant ("" :: String)
                           , toVariant ("" :: String)
                           , toVariant ([""] :: [String])
                           , toVariant (Nothing :: Maybe [(String, Variant)]) -- compilation error
                           , toVariant (2000 :: Int32) ]
        }
```

but the above fails to compile because there is `No instance for (IsVariant (Maybe [(String, Variant)]))`.

An earlier attempt was to do

```hs
                           , toVariant ([] :: [(String, Variant)]) -- compilation error
```

but while this compiles, it errors with

```
mynot: ClientError {clientErrorMessage = "Call failed: Type of message, \8220(susssasa(sv)i)\8221, does not match expected type \8220(susssasa{sv}i)\8221", clientErrorFatal = False}
```

where the type `[(String, Variant)]` seems to map to `a(sv)`, but I'd need a `a{sv}`.

Comment: Given that `a{sv}` [is a dictionary](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#container-types), my guess is that you can use the `Map` instance of [`IsVariant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus-1.3.2/docs/DBus.html#t:IsVariant).

Comment: @duplode, that was it :| Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a{sv}` [is a dictionary type in D-Bus](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#container-types). On the Haskell side, the dictionaries correspond to [`Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.7/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html), which has a [`IsVariant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus-1.3.2/docs/DBus.html#t:IsVariant) instance. That being so, with an...

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
```

... you can supply an empty map for the hints:

```
-- etc.
    , toVariant (Map.empty :: Map.Map String Variant)
```