# How can I write a notification server in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, notifications, dbus, libnotify

[I tried to understand a bit better how notifications work on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767743/how-do-notifications-work-on-linux/), then I played around with the [`dbus` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus) and, after [some silly mistakes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78036559/how-do-i-crate-a-value-of-type-asv-for-a-call-to-org-freedesktop-notifications), I managed to write a toy "client" that when executed requests the notification server to show a hardcoded message.

But now my interest is: is the `dbus` library also useful if I want to write a notification *server*?

If yes, then can you point me at the relevant part of the documentation?

If no, then what else can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the name "`Client`", yes, `Dbus.Client` is also used for writing dbus-based servers. The relevant documentation section is labeled [Receiving method calls](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus-1.3.2/docs/DBus-Client.html#g:5).

Comment: Can you guide to an example usage? For instance, the only meaty snippet I see there is under `export`. If I understand correctly, two methods are implemented, and since they both return `IO Smth`, I guess I could change their impls to _print "I've been called" to a file_ to see them in action. But the example seems wrong, e.g. `ping` likely lacks a `return`, `method` doesn't seem to exist, and `autoMethod` is given 3 args but its signature says it takes 2. As regards how to trigger the implemented functions, I guess I'd use `dbus-send` [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34506969/5825294).