# How do I make a minimal working example for the a DBus server?

Tags: haskell, server, functional-programming, dbus

[In the doc for `DBus`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus-1.3.2/docs/DBus-Client.html#g:5) there's this example,

```hs
ping :: MethodCall -> IO Reply
ping _ = ReplyReturn []

sayHello :: String -> IO String
sayHello name = return ("Hello " ++ name ++ "!")

 export client "/hello_world"
   defaultInterface { interfaceName = "com.example.HelloWorld"
                    , interfaceMethods =
                      [ method "com.example.HelloWorld" "Ping" ping
                      , autoMethod "com.example.HelloWorld" "Hello" sayHello
                      ]
                    }
```

[which should help me understand how to implement a dbus-based server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78049106/how-can-i-write-a-notification-server-in-haskell).

However, the example seems a bit outdated in several respects:

- I can't find `method` in that documentation (there's related [`Method`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus-1.3.2/docs/DBus-Client.html#t:Method), [`makeMethod`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus-1.3.2/docs/DBus-Client.html#v:makeMethod), [`autoMethod`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus-1.3.2/docs/DBus-Client.html#v:autoMethod));
- by looking at those, I think that also `ping` has an outdate signature, and maybe it should return `DBusR Reply` instead of `IO Reply`;
- `autoMethod` is given 3 arguments but it should be given 2, and just removing `"Hello"` makes it typecheck, but... I've read [`AutoMethod`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus-1.3.2/docs/DBus-Client.html#t:AutoMethod)'s doc, but I don't really understand that.

But most importantly the example is incomplete. How do I make use of it?

The doc for [`export`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus-1.3.2/docs/DBus-Client.html#v:export) reads

> Export the given [`Interface`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus-1.3.2/docs/DBus-Client.html#t:Interface) at the given [`ObjectPath`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus-1.3.2/docs/DBus-Internal-Types.html#t:ObjectPath)

makes me think all I have to do is to put the last piece of the snippet (the call to `export`) in a `main :: IO ()` function, and then keep it alive with `_ <- getChar` or something before `return ()`, but I still have no clue how to... have those functions `sayHello` and `ping` be called. Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34506969/5825294) I kinda feel that I should use `dbus-send`, but with whatever Haskell nonsense I've managed to compile based on the above code snippet, if I run

```bash
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest="com.example.HelloWorld" /hello_world com.example.HelloWorld.Ping
```

I get

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name is not activatable
```

which, given my knowledge at the present time, can be because of some unrelated-to-Haskell set-up I supposed to do, as well as because I wrote Haskell nonsense.

---

Anyway, here's some code I managed to compile, but that doesn't actually do anything:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import DBus
import DBus.Client

ping :: MethodCall -> IO Reply
ping _ = return (ReplyReturn [])

sayHello :: String -> IO String
sayHello name = return ("Hello " ++ name ++ "!")

main :: IO ()
main = do
    client <- connectSession

    export client "/hello_world"
        defaultInterface { interfaceName = "com.example.HelloWorld"
                         , interfaceMethods =
                           [
                           autoMethod "com.example.HelloWorld" sayHello
                           ]
                         }
    _ <- getLine
    return ()
```

Comment: Is this the full code? How did you set up `client`? Did you call `requestName` at any point?

Comment: @user1686, I haven't. I'm now trying to understand what the documentation means :/ `rnr <- requestName client "com.example.HelloWorld" []; print rnr` seems to... do stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name is not activatable
> ```

The error message is talking about *bus names,* which are basically the "addresses" of each service (or even each client) on the bus. Most importantly, it means that the requested `--dest=` name is currently *not present* on the bus.

(Alongside that, the error message also means dbus-daemon doesn't know how to start your service on-demand, but you can safely ignore that – "activation" is just the auto-start mechanism and is not relevant when you're manually starting your service.)

Bus names are not set through configuration (that's only for auto-start); they're "claimed" by the service using a special bus call, every time it starts up and connects to the bus. Your process needs to call `requestName` ([docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus-1.3.2/docs/DBus-Client.html#g:9)) to make that happen.

Examples (I don't know enough Haskell to make much sense of them):

- https://github.com/abbradar/haskell-dbus/blob/9b50453f563423a00308e9b8e7352b3ef4f64c79/examples/export.hs#L42
- https://github.com/kamek-pf/ntfd/blob/7fb5de92f6930f098800d2f01adf7295d829222b/app/Main.hs#L32
- https://github.com/adelsz/mnotify/blob/37c59688ea79b7bd7508bb836f81183e84c752eb/NotifyServer.hs#L57
- https://sources.debian.org/src/taffybar/4.0.1-1/src/System/Taffybar/Widget/FreedesktopNotifications.hs/?hl=156#L156
- https://sources.debian.org/src/xmobar/0.46-3/src/Xmobar/System/DBus.hs/?hl=44#L44

(The interface name is **not** that – interfaces are just something your own code uses to group or distinguish methods, whereas the service name (aka bus name, aka unique name) is the actual "D-Bus address" of your whole process. For a simple 1-object, 1-interface service they're very likely to be identical, but if you browse through `d-spy` you'll see many examples where a service makes many objects available, and which have multiple interfaces, all at a single bus name.)

Ideally, the bus name should be claimed *after* the initial objects have been set up and exported, to prevent cases where calls to your service fail with "no such object" or similar because it just happened to arrive a moment too early.

Answer (score 3):

That example is so outdated, it looks like it predates `dbus-0.10`, the earliest version of the package that's actually available on Hackage.

A self-contained rewrite that works in dbus-1.3.2 is as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main (main) where

import DBus
import DBus.Client
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad

ping :: MethodCall -> IO Reply
ping _ = pure $ ReplyReturn []

sayHello :: String -> IO String
sayHello name = return ("Hello " ++ name ++ "!")

main :: IO ()
main = do
  client <- connectSession
  requestResult <- requestName client "com.example.HelloWorld" []
  when (requestResult /= NamePrimaryOwner) $ do
    error "Service already in use"
  export client "/hello_world"
    defaultInterface { interfaceName = "com.example.HelloWorld"
                     , interfaceMethods =
                       [ makeMethod "Ping"
                         (signature_ [TypeString])
                         (signature_ [TypeString])
                         (liftIO . ping)
                       , autoMethod "Hello" sayHello
                       ]
                     }

  -- wait forever for calls
  forever (threadDelay 1000000)
```

It will respond to requests as long as its running.

```
$ dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest="com.example.HelloWorld" \
> /hello_world com.example.HelloWorld.Ping string:'example.com'
method return time=1708979166.466824 sender=:1.118 -> destination=:1.119 serial=3 reply_serial=2
$ dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest="com.example.HelloWorld" \
> /hello_world com.example.HelloWorld.Hello string:'world'
method return time=1708979185.572916 sender=:1.118 -> destination=:1.120 serial=4 reply_serial=2
   string "Hello world!"
```

Be warned that if you try to test this in GHCi, even after `main` has exited or been interrupted with Ctrl-C, the child thread servicing requests will continue to run in the background, so if you rerun the server from the same GHCi session, you'll probably get an error:

```
*** Exception: Service already in use
```

and need to restart GHCi.